# php difference in time

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following code to insert three times and get the difference between `out` and `max` of `edin` and `adin`.

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
    $insertSQL = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO chk (edin, adin, `out`, diff) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['edin'], "date"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['adin'], "date"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['out'], "date"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['out'] - max($_POST['adin'], $_POST['edin']), "date")
    );
}
```

I wonder why this works fine when I use 'int' and it calculates the max value, then gives the difference between the `out` and `max` of other two. with datetime it's not working.

Comment: you can't just do arithmetic on a date string

Comment: thanks for your comment. so how do i do the calculation if not arithmatic? could you please help? thanks again.

Comment: use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`